# xlog flush request is not satisfied in log files

Tags: postgresql

Today I saw that Postgres produces error messages related to possible data corruption (?). Everything's working as expected so I didn't realize anything was wrong.

```
ERROR:  xlog flush request 6E/82FFED10 is not satisfied --- flushed only to 3D/CA02E920
CONTEXT:  writing block 1008 of relation base/118517/118823
CONTEXT:  writing block 1008 of relation base/118517/118823
WARNING:  could not write block 1008 of base/118517/118823
LOG:  request to flush past end of generated WAL; request 6E/82FFED10, currpos 3D/CA02E920
DETAIL:  Multiple failures --- write error might be permanent.
```

PostgreSQL 11. 
Configuration:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 16GB
effective_cache_size = 48GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 41943kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 8
```

```
pg_control version number:            1100
Catalog version number:               201809051
Database system identifier:           6775130872383000604
Database cluster state:               in production
pg_control last modified:             Thu Mar 12 04:46:20 2020
Latest checkpoint location:           85/802C9268
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:    85/802C9230
Latest checkpoint's REDO WAL file:    000000010000008500000080
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's PrevTimeLineID:   1
Latest checkpoint's full_page_writes: on
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0:69393025
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          511846
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  11365
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  23069
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        562
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  69393025
Latest checkpoint's oldestMultiXid:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestMulti's DB: 1
Latest checkpoint's oldestCommitTsXid:0
Latest checkpoint's newestCommitTsXid:0
Time of latest checkpoint:            Thu Mar 12 04:45:50 2020
Fake LSN counter for unlogged rels:   0/1
Minimum recovery ending location:     0/0
Min recovery ending loc's timeline:   0
Backup start location:                0/0
Backup end location:                  0/0
End-of-backup record required:        no
wal_level setting:                    replica
wal_log_hints setting:                off
max_connections setting:              100
max_worker_processes setting:         8
max_prepared_xacts setting:           0
max_locks_per_xact setting:           64
track_commit_timestamp setting:       off
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Size of a large-object chunk:         2048
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by value
Data page checksum version:           0
Mock authentication nonce:            edec50c3ef6ee1a42351c2e593de539feb25343ad239e12b813b4c212ae2a1d6
```

I did a backup and then I restored it to another database and removed the old one. It didn't work. I still getting those errors.

P.S. PostgreSQL did not crash lately. There is also a plenty of space on SSD.

Comment: Which command/tool did you use to generate the third output from the top, first from the bottom?

Comment: @dw8547, it is output from pg_controldata https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgcontroldata.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes that looks like corruption, perhaps caused by storage hardware problems.

Perform a `pg_dumpall` of the cluster and restore it to a newly created cluster, that should get rid of the problem.

Check your hardware.

Comment: smartctl does not show any disk errors. hmm...

Answer (score 1):

According to the provided log, the problem is related to the data file corrupt - which might be caused by the improper shutdown. One of data files has become corrupted.

The file location should be `$PGDATA/base/118517/118823`

### Recommended Action:

First of all, its important to keep in mind that this error is about the pages written to the data directory, not about the WAL stream. That means the primary aim here, if the data of a table is indeed lost, is to get a copy of the data from the WAL stream.

Before we go into details on how to do that, lets first find out which table or index is affected.

In the log message `could not write block 1008 of base/118517/118823` we get the following information:

- 118823 is the pg_class.relfilenode value of the **index** or **table** affected
- 118517 is the database OID, i.e. pg_database.oid
- 1008 is the block number, from which we can determine the file segment as well as the location within the file

That means we can find the affected table by first doing the following to locate the correct database:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 118517;
```

And then **connecting to that database** and running the following, which gives us the affected table or index:

```
SELECT relname, relkind FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = 118823;
```

If the affected database object is an index(could be determined by the **relkind** value of the query above), it is lucky for you - you could just rebuild the index to fix everything.

If the affected database object is a table - bad luck - the available options are:

- Fail over to an HA standby server / follower database
- Replay WAL from an old enough base backup
- Accept that some data is lost, and let Postgres move on. You could try to dump the data of the table (might get error during dumping, and lost some data) , and then truncate the table.