# PostgreSQL does not start: FATAL: xlog flush request is not satisfied --- flushed only to 0

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a Docker PostgreSQL (TimescaleDB) developer instance with a local Linux volume mapping.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  dex-timeseriesdb:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754077/315168
    shm_size: 1g
    container_name: dex-timeseriesdb
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    volumes:
       - $PWD/data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

After unclean shutdown the instance no longer starts with `FATAL:  xlog flush request 0/2CEFA910 is not satisfied --- flushed only to 0/1B48258` error:

```
dex-timeseriesdb    |
dex-timeseriesdb    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
dex-timeseriesdb    |
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:47.330 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:47.330 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:47.330 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:47.336 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:47.486 UTC [21] LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2021-06-13 18:47:35 UTC
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.629 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.645 UTC [21] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1B46C68
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.648 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1B48258: wanted 24, got 0
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.648 UTC [21] LOG:  redo done at 0/1B48220
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.697 UTC [21] LOG:  request to flush past end of generated WAL; request 0/2CEFA910, currpos 0/1B48258
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.697 UTC [21] CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/13455/16573_vm
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.697 UTC [21] FATAL:  xlog flush request 0/2CEFA910 is not satisfied --- flushed only to 0/1B48258
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.697 UTC [21] CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/13455/16573_vm
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.701 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 21) exited with exit code 1
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.701 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
dex-timeseriesdb    | 2021-06-13 18:50:49.744 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

This is likely data corruption due to unclean Docker shutdown.

There is nothing important in the database. However, I would still like to learn if it is possible to recover the database in situations like this, instead of rebuilding it from the scratch or restoring from a backup.

I tested that the volume mapping is writable within the Docker instance using shell, so that should not be an issue.

See also [similar question regarding FATAL: xlog flush request, but slightly different error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261756/xlog-flush-request-is-not-satisfied-in-log-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the provided log, the problem is related to the data file corrupt - which might be caused by the improper shutdown. One of data files has become corrupted.

The file location should be `$PGDATA/base/13455/16573_vm`

### Recommended Action:

First of all, its important to keep in mind that this error is about the pages written to the data directory, not about the WAL stream. That means the primary aim here, if the data of a table is indeed lost, is to get a copy of the data from the WAL stream.

Before we go into details on how to do that, lets first find out which table or index is affected.

In the log message `invalid page in block 0 of relation base/13455/16573_vm` we get the following information:

- 16573 is the pg_class.relfilenode value of the index or table affected
- 13455is the database OID, i.e. pg_database.oid
- 0 is the block number, from which we can determine the file segment as well as the location within the file

That means we can find the affected table by first doing the following to locate the correct database:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 13455;
```

And then connecting to that database and running the following, which gives us the affected table or index:

```
SELECT relname, relkind FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = 16573;
```

If the affected database object is an index, it is lucky for you - you could just rebuild the index to fix everything.

If the affected database object is a table - bad luck - the available options are:

- Fail over to an HA standby server / follower database
- Replay WAL from an old enough base backup
- Accept that some data is lost, and let Postgres move on. You could try to dump the data of the table (might get error during dumping, and lost some data) , and then truncate the table.

Comment: How can you do all these fancy `SELECT`s if the Postgres instance refuses to start though?

Comment: @mustaccio , I run `pg_resetwal /var/lib/postgresql/data` (run `su postgres` before execution) to fix the problem (add `-f` if necessary) and get the database up. Notice that the version sould be 10 or later.

Comment: And note that `pg_resetwal` will corrupt your database even further.

Comment: Reply to @mustaccio, if you could not start the server (in my case, I could start the server. but the server got crashed when I tried to access the broken data), you can go to the `$PGDATA` and find out the corresponding data file. If the data file name is suffixed by `_fsm` or `_vm`, it could be sure that the data file is for an table object. If the data file name only contains numbers, and have file(s) together with the same number but has  `_fsm` or `_vm` suffix, it is table object too. Or else, you could just try to open the file guess by the content, it is not hare even they are binaries.